# PDA and a regular expression

Tags: regular-language, pushdown-automaton

I have a PDA and some regular expression. Is there any algorithm I can use to make sure my PDA  accepts strings that are subset of what could be produced by the regular expression ?

Thanks!

Gil

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking this: given a PDA M and a regular expression r, produce a PDA which accepts the language L(M) intersect L(r). If this is what you want, the answer is yes, and the construction is tedious but straightforward:

1. transform the regular expression r into a NFA N using some construction, e.g., one used in a constructive proof of the equivalence of regular expressions and finite automata
2. determinize the NFA N to get a DFA M' using some construction, e.g., the powerset (or subset) construction, or any used in a constructive proof of the equivalence of nondeterministic and deterministic FAs
3. optionally, minimize M' to get M'', using some DFA minimization algorithm
4. now, construct the new PDA P as follows:

   - the states will be all ordered pairs (a, b) where a is a state in the PDA M and b is a state in the DFA M''
   - the transitions will be from state (a, b) to (a', b') on symbol s whenever a transitions to a' on s in PDA M and b transitions to b' on s in DFA M'' (for epsilon-transitions, go from (a, b) to (a', b)).
   - the initial state (ai, bi) will be comprised of the initial states ai and bi of the PDA M and DFA M'', respectively
   - the accepting states  will be those where BOTH components are accepting in their respective machines (pairs (a, b) where a is accepting in PDA M and b is accepting in DFA M'')
   - the stack is updated according to the transitions from PDA M alone

A machine so constructed will accept everything that is both accepted by PDA M and matched by regular expression r.

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Helped me understand this problem abit more.